# How do I insert the value of a configuration variable in Vim?

Tags: vim

I can get the value of the `guifont` configuration value by typing:

```
:set guifont?
```

And I could remember it and then type it. But is there a way to directly insert that value into my document?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

In [Insert-mode](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#Insert-mode):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>r</kbd>`=&guifont`<kbd>enter</kbd>

See these help pages for more information on how this works:

- [**`:help i_CTRL-R_=`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#i_CTRL-R_=)
- [**`:help expr-option`**](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#expr-option)

Comment: This is great. The same sequence `<C-R>=` is great [integer calculations](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_vim_as_calculator), too!

Comment: Happy to help. `<C-R>=` is a powerful weapon to have in your arsenal. Particularly if you play [VimGolf](http://vimgolf.com/)!

Answer (score 8):

You can redirect ex output with the `redir` command:

```
:redir @a
:set guifont?
:redir END
"ap
```

Comment: 3 great answers, but this one seems the most powerful and general to me.  Tucking it away safely in my toolbox.

Answer (score 4):

Sure. For example, to add a line at the top of the document with the value of the `shiftwidth` option I can do:

```
:execute append(0, &shiftwidth)
```

You can type this in directly but more typically it would appear without the `:` in a function defined in *vimrc.*

See [*Write a Vim script*.](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/usr_41.html)